# Best practice table in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, performance, sapui5

I already used `sap.m.Table` directly with OData and also with *JSON*. But what is the best practice to display let's say 500+ items with for example 7 columns.
Should I load the OData into a local *JSON* Model or use OData directly with growing functionality (pagination)?

**[edited version + research below]**

According to the API of [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html)

- > ... For mobile devices, the recommended limit of table rows is 100 (based on 4 columns) to assure proper performance. To improve initial rendering on large tables, use the growing feature

According to the API of [sap.ui.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html)

- > Provides a comprehensive set of features for displaying and dealing with vast amounts of data.
- > the Table control reuses its DOM elements of the rows. When the user scrolls, only the row contexts are changed but the rendered controls remain the same

So one has to work with the growing functionality anyway?

Answer (score 3):

it's not recommended to use `sap.m.Table` for more than 100 items and approximately 4 columns. Otherwise there could occur performance problems. for big data `sap.ui.table.Table` suits best. therefore, with > 500 rows and 7 columns `sap.ui.table.Table` is the one to choose. best practice is to use directly the odata model.

Comment: Do you have any source for that claim?

Comment: @Marc It's also mentioned in the doc. "Large number of rows (> 100): sap.ui.table.Table" https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/148892ff9aea4a18b912829791e38f3e